# Qt5 Syntax Highlighting in QML

Tags: syntax-highlighting, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am working on a `QtQuick 2.0` presentation and I would like to embed some code samples. is it possible easily to create a syntax highlighting QML element.

The objective in question is to apply syntax highlighting to a `TextEdit` or a `TextArea`. I know Qt has a `QSyntaxHighlighter`, but the documentation is not very clear on how exactly to apply it to a `TextEdit` or a `TextArea`.

Can you provide examples on how it's done?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how did @JamesTurner's answer brought you a solution? I am unable to do that with TextArea in Qt 5.6.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy No I don't have any code I could share with you. What is your problem?

Comment: I found that "selectionColor" is a good property for this. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-textarea-members.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Qt Quick's `TextEdit` item exposes a `textDocument` property, of type `QQuickTextDocument`. This is explicitly exposed so you can use `QSyntaxHighlighter` directly with the document.

[QtQuick textEdit documentation for Qt 5.3](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#textDocument-prop)

Answer (score 11):

I have two answers:

1. a pure QML answer
2. a C++ answer involving [QSyntaxHighlighter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html)

For a pure QML answer, we can use a [TextArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html) one can set [TextArea::textFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#textFormat-prop) to `textFormat: TextEdit.RichText` for formatting. We can use [TextArea::getText()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#getText-method) to get the plain text and set [TextArea::text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#text-prop) with the rich text. Here's a mock example that:

- color uppercase identifiers (e.g. Button) as purple
- color lowercase identifiers (e.g. x y z) as red
- color numbers (e.g. 123 456) as blue
- but leave symbols (e.g. = + ;) as black

Here's the snippet:

```javascript
    TextArea {
        id: output

        property bool processing: false

        text: "<p>x = 123;</p><p>y = 456;</p><p>z = x + y;</p>"
        textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
        selectByMouse: true

        onTextChanged: {
            if (!processing) {
                processing = true;
                let p = cursorPosition;
                let markUp = getText(0, length).replace(
                  /([A-Z][A-Za-z]*|[a-z][A-Za-z]*|[0-9]+|[ \t\n]|['][^']*[']|[^A-Za-z0-9\t\n ])/g,
                    function (f) {
                        console.log("f: ", JSON.stringify(f));
                        if (f.match(/^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*$/))
                            return "<span style='color:#800080'>" + f + "</span>";
                        if (f.match(/^[a-z][A-Za-z]*$/))
                            return "<span style='color:#800000'>" + f + "</span>";
                        else if (f.match(/^[0-9]+$/))
                            return "<span style='color:#0000ff'>" + f + "</span>";
                        else if (f.match(/^[ ]/))
                            return "&nbsp;"
                        else if (f.match(/^[\t\n]/))
                            return f;
                        else if (f.match(/^[']/))
                            return "<span style='color:#008000'>" + f + "</span>";
                        else
                            return f;
                    }
                );
                text = markUp;
                cursorPosition = p;
                processing = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

To use Qt's [QSyntaxHighlighter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html), you need the following:

1. In QML, use [TextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html) QML type in your application
2. In C++, define a [QSyntaxHighlighter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) and connect TextEdit QML type to it via the [TextEdit::textDocument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#textDocument-prop) property
3. In C++, implement [QSyntaxHighlighter::highlightBlock( const QString& text )](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#highlightBlock) in your derived class, calling [QSyntaxHighlighter::setFormat()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#setFormat) as often as needed to tokenize the text found.

To make things easier, I create a sample app https://github.com/stephenquan/QtSyntaxHighlighterApp which wraps [QSyntaxHighlighter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) and [QTextFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextformat.html) as `SyntaxHighlighter` and `TextFormat` QML Types. That way, one can handle onHighlightBlock signal and put the business logic of the syntax highlighter in Javascript instead of C++:

```javascript
TextEdit {
    id: textEdit
    selectByMouse: true
    text: [
        "import QtQuick 2.12",
        "",
        "Item {",
        "    Rectangle {",
        "        width: 50",
        "        height: 50",
        "        color: '#800000'",
        "    }",
        "}",
    ].join("\n") + "\n"
    font.pointSize: 12
}

SyntaxHighlighter {
    id: syntaxHighlighter
    textDocument: textEdit.textDocument
    onHighlightBlock: {
        let rx = /\/\/.*|[A-Za-z.]+(\s*:)?|\d+(.\d*)?|'[^']*?'|"[^"]*?"/g;
        let m;
        while ( ( m = rx.exec(text) ) !== null ) {
            if (m[0].match(/^\/\/.*/)) {
                setFormat(m.index, m[0].length, commentFormat);
                continue;
            }
            if (m[0].match(/^[a-z][A-Za-z.]*\s*:/)) {
                setFormat(m.index, m[0].match(/^[a-z][A-Za-z.]*/)[0].length, propertyFormat);
                continue;
            }
            if (m[0].match(/^[a-z]/)) {
                let keywords = [ 'import', 'function', 'bool', 'var',
                                'int', 'string', 'let', 'const', 'property',
                                'if', 'continue', 'for', 'break', 'while',
                    ];
                if (keywords.includes(m[0])) {
                    setFormat(m.index, m[0].length, keywordFormat);
                    continue;
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (m[0].match(/^[A-Z]/)) {
                setFormat(m.index, m[0].length, componentFormat);
                continue;
            }
            if (m[0].match(/^\d/)) {
                setFormat(m.index, m[0].length, numberFormat);
                continue;
            }
            if (m[0].match(/^'/)) {
                setFormat(m.index, m[0].length, stringFormat);
                continue;
            }
            if (m[0].match(/^"/)) {
                setFormat(m.index, m[0].length, stringFormat);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

TextCharFormat { id: keywordFormat; foreground: "#808000" }
TextCharFormat { id: componentFormat; foreground: "#aa00aa"; font.pointSize: 12; font.bold: true; font.italic: true }
TextCharFormat { id: numberFormat; foreground: "#0055af" }
TextCharFormat { id: propertyFormat; foreground: "#800000" }
TextCharFormat { id: stringFormat; foreground: "green" }
TextCharFormat { id: commentFormat; foreground: "green" }
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no obvious way to achieve syntax highlighting in QML.

One could implement one's own declarative item, performing the actual highlighting with  [`QSyntaxHighlighter`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) but then one would have to define its own highlighting rules for language of the source code in question. I would't do that amount of coding for a presentation.

Instead I would display the code in a [`WebView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qml-qtwebkit3-webview.html) item with the highlighting already applied as static HTML markup or with the help of a JavaScript highlighting library, for expample [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/).

### Update 1

If the `WebView` item is indeed unusable, even the simple [`Text`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-text.html) item with its [rudimentary HTML support](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/richtext-html-subset.html) should be enough to handle the source code highlighting usecase if fed with static HTML.

Comment: That came across my mind but unfortunately the QtQuick2 WebView element has some mobile devices sizing optimizations which don't really work well with presentations which size should be dynamically applied. (FullScreen)

Answer (score 5):

in your app file:

```cpp
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
QQuickTextDocument* doc = childObject<QQuickTextDocument*>(engine, "textEditor", "textDocument");
Q_ASSERT(doc != 0);

// QSyntaxHighlighter derrived class
MySyntaxHighlighter* parser = new MySyntaxHighlighter(doc->textDocument());
// use parser, see QSyntaxHighlighter doc...
int ret = app.exec();
delete parser;
return ret;
```

The template function to get child objects (returns the first occurence of objectName, so use unique names to identify objects in your qml files) :

```cpp
template <class T> T childObject(QQmlApplicationEngine& engine,
                                 const QString& objectName,
                                 const QString& propertyName)
{
    QList<QObject*> rootObjects = engine.rootObjects();
    foreach (QObject* object, rootObjects)
    {
        QObject* child = object->findChild<QObject*>(objectName);
        if (child != 0)
        {
            std::string s = propertyName.toStdString();
            QObject* object = child->property(s.c_str()).value<QObject*>();
            Q_ASSERT(object != 0);
            T prop = dynamic_cast<T>(object);
            Q_ASSERT(prop != 0);
            return prop;
        }
    }
    return (T) 0;
}
```

in your qml file use a TextEdit (inside a Flickable or whatever you want) with the objectName property correctly set:

```js
.... 
TextEdit {
    id: edit
    objectName: "textEditor"
    width: flick.width
    height: flick.height
    focus: true
    font.family: "Courier New"
    font.pointSize: 12
    wrapMode: TextEdit.NoWrap
    onCursorRectangleChanged: flick.ensureVisible(cursorRectangle)
}
....
```

Comment: This does not work because QSyntaxHighlighter is an abstract class.

Comment: You are right. Use a QSyntaxHighlighter derived class.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [QSyntaxHighlighter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsyntaxhighlighter.html).

If you need a QML Item doing syntax highlighting, you can simply create your own by extending `QDeclarativeItem` and using the utility above.