# How to add color on specific words on QML Text

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Hello i would like to add different color on specific words of a string to be used in QML Text

```
Text {

    text: "Blue Red Yellow Green"

}
```

I know that you can add color to the whole text, but i would like to add specific color on specific words. is this possible? and how is it achieved?

Comment: Your original question is on Text and, the accepted answer is appropriate. However, your following up question is on TextInput/TextArea or TextEdit. That is covered under syntax highlighting, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791360/qt5-syntax-highlighting-in-qml

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Text` items can display both plain and rich text. For example you can have:

```
Text {
    text: "<font color=\"#0000FF\">Blue</font> <font color=\"#FF0000\">Red</font>"
}
```

Comment: Great answer sir, Thank you ! But i do have a follow up question, is there a way to do it in TextInput or TextArea too?  I did try it but shows me the plain text version

Comment: @Jack You can not have rich text in `TextInput`. But it's stated in the Qt documentation that you can have rich text in `TextEdit` and `TextArea`.

Comment: i tried using your string of text , and  it would seem TextEdit and textArea show the plain text, i looked at the documentation and there seem to be no property that enable or disables it. any ideas?

Comment: @Jack You should set the property `textFormat: TextEdit.RichText`.

Comment: Oh, that is my bad i missed that one. Thank you very much sir this is very helpful